# Show that we can use a sequence $(\phi_n)$ to induce continuous functionals

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(\phi_n) \subset C[-1,1]$. Show that we can use a sequence $(\phi_n)$ to induce continuous functionals in $C[-1,1]$ where the dual pair is

$$\langle \phi_n, f \rangle=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)\phi(t)dt, \ f \in C[-1,1]$$

Comment: I did not understand what I have to do what I have to prove that is functional?

Comment: Yes, if $\phi$ is continuous, $L_\phi:f\longmapsto \int \phi f$ is a bounded linear functional for the sup norm over $[-1,1]$. Is it what you are asking? Then it is clear that it is linear. Then try to show that $|L_\phi f|\leq C \|f\|_\infty$ for some constant $C$ depending on $\phi$. This will prove boudnedness=continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Each $\phi_n$ defines a map $T_n f = \int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,\phi_n(t)\,dt$ which is clearly linear and satisfies $|T_n f|\le \|f\|\int_{-1}^1 |\phi_n|\,dt $.

I think the point of considering a *sequence* of $\phi_n$ is the following: assuming that there is a constant $M$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 |\phi_n|\,dt\le M$ for all $n$, we can apply the Banach-Alaoglu theorem to conclude that the sequence $\{T_n\}\subset C[-1,1]^*$ has  at least one limit point $T$ in the weak* topology. This $T$ can be called a  functional induced by the sequence $\phi_n$.

Important example: $\phi_n(t)=\max(n^2-n|t|,0)$. Then $\int_{-1}^1 |\phi_n|\,dt=1$ for all $n$. This time, the sequence $T_n$ has a limit in the weak* topology: the evaluation functional $f\mapsto f(0)$.